# "pyinstalller " no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo , programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Estoy empezando en python e hice una calculadora simple y a la hora de "transformarlo" en un archivo.exe ejecutable pongo , 
"pyinstaller practicaCalculadora.py" (asi se llama el proyecto), y me aparece lo que se ve en la imagen.

*ya tengo instalado "pyinstaller" [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando ocurre este error al escribir el comando python en consola, lo primordial es chequear que Python esté instalado. Para ello te recomiendo revisar la ruta raíz de tu computadora (C:\, por ejemplo) para ver si encuentras una carpeta del estilo PythonXY (e.g. Python36) o PythonXY-32. En caso negativo, sigue las instrucciones del tutorial

> Te sugiero que chequees la
>   ubicación C:\Users[Usuario]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python que es la
>   ruta configurada por defecto en el instalador.
>
> Ahora bien, una vez identificado el directorio de instalación, vayamos
>   a la sección de Configuración (a partir de Windows 10) o bien Panel de
>   control (Windows 8 y anteriores).
>
> Una vez abierta, ubiquemos la sección de búsqueda y escribamos
>   «variab» (sin comillas).
>
> Entre las opciones desplegadas seleccionaremos Editar las variables de
>   entorno de esta cuenta, lo que abrirá un nuevo recuadro. En la primera
>   lista busquemos la variable de nombre PATH, la seleccionamos y luego
>   presionamos el botón Editar.
>
> Allí vamos a presionar el botón Nuevo para añadir un elemento y
>   escribiremos la ruta de instalación de Python que identificamos al
>   principio, seguido de la tecla Enter. Repetimos este paso pero
>   añadiendo la carpeta Scripts a la ruta, como se muestra en la imagen
>   (esto permite evitar errores como «pip» no se reconoce como un
>   comando…).
>
> Hecho esto, cliqueamos Aceptar en ambos recuadros y nos dirijimos a la
>   consola para chequear que todo haya salido bien. Presionamos la tecla
>   Windows + R, escribimos cmd y Aceptar (o bien buscamos la aplicación
>   de nombre Símbolo del sistema). Esto abrirá la consola.
>
> https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/python-no-se-reconoce-como-un-comando-interno-o-externo/

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], edita y agrega mas contenido a tu respuesta, puedes dejar los enlaces como referencias